# css link not being recognized

Tags: php, html, css

Here is a strange one. At least for me anyway. I have an HTML page that is being generated by PHP with a style sheet (css.php) linked in. My original plan was to be able to save the attributes for this file in a MySQL database and then load values into the file using PHP variables at each page load. I was talked out of this because it would use to many server resources to parse this file on each page load. I decided to rewrite this file each time changes were made to the database. Now that I have written a file with preferences.php and changed its name to css.css it no longer sees the correct file. It only sees a one line file that I wrote while initially setting up my code. Now that I have a full file it still uses the one-liner that no longer exists. If I change back to my .php file that is in the same folder (the only difference between the two is the file extension) everything works correctly? Where have I gone wrong? I'm sure it's something simple that I can't see.

here is index.html that is loading the css file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
    <head>
        <title>Rogers Enterprises</title>
        <link rel= "icon" type= "image/png" href= "images/bc2.JPG">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/css.css" >
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    </head>
```

and here is my css.css

```
body { background: linear-gradient(to top right, #ffff00 0%, #000000 100%);
                   color: #ddd8e4; }

            h1 { color: red;
                 text-align: center; }

            div { /*border: 1px solid black; */
                  padding: 1%;
                  float: left; }

            p.content { text-indent: 2%; }
            p.content::first-letter { font-size: 200%;
                                      font-weight: bold;
                                      color: black }

            #logo { width: 98%; }

            .box { width: 10%; }

            #links { width: 100%; }

            #desc { width: 86%; }

            #footer { width: 98%;
                      background-color: #104e01;
                      display: block; 
                      text-align: center; }

            .footer { width: 31.33%; }

            #login {opacity: 0.2; }

            #login-form { max-width: 100%;
                          display: inline-block;
                          margin-left: auto;
                          margin-right: auto;
                          text-align: left; }

            input { border-radius: 5px;
                    max-width: 25vw; }
            img { max-width: 100%;
                  max-height: 100%; }


            /* styles for smart phone */

            @media only screen and (min-width: 302px) and (max-width: 640px) { 

                .box{ position: relative;
                      width: 98%; }         /* desired width */
                .box:before{ content: "";
                             display: block;
                             padding-top: 16.66666666%; } /*What you want the height to be in relation to the width */
                .box-content{ position:  absolute;
                              top: 0;
                              left: 0;
                              bottom: 0;
                              right: 0; }

                #desc { width: 98%; }

            }

            @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 370px) {

                #remember_me_label { font-size: 4vw; }

            }

            /* styles for tablet */

            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { /* styles for tablet */

            }
```

This is preferences.php that generates the CSS

```
$file = fopen("../css/css.css", "w");
    $txt = 'body { background: linear-gradient(to top right, #ffff00 0%, #000000 100%);
                   color: #ddd8e4; }

            h1 { color: red;
                 text-align: center; }

            div { /*border: 1px solid black; */
                  padding: 1%;
                  float: left; }

            p.content { text-indent: 2%; }
            p.content::first-letter { font-size: 200%;
                                      font-weight: bold;
                                      color: black }

            #logo { width: 98%; }

            .box { width: 10%; }

            #links { width: 100%; }

            #desc { width: 86%; }

            #footer { width: 98%;
                      background-color: #104e01;
                      display: block; 
                      text-align: center; }

            .footer { width: 31.33%; }

            #login {opacity: 0.2; }

            #login-form { max-width: 100%;
                          display: inline-block;
                          margin-left: auto;
                          margin-right: auto;
                          text-align: left; }

            input { border-radius: 5px;
                    max-width: 25vw; }
            img { max-width: 100%;
                  max-height: 100%; }


            /* styles for smart phone */

            @media only screen and (min-width: 302px) and (max-width: 640px) { 

                .box{ position: relative;
                      width: 98%; }         /* desired width */
                .box:before{ content: "";
                             display: block;
                             padding-top: 16.66666666%; } /*What you want the height to be in relation to the width */
                .box-content{ position:  absolute;
                              top: 0;
                              left: 0;
                              bottom: 0;
                              right: 0; }

                #desc { width: 98%; }

            }

            @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 370px) {

                #remember_me_label { font-size: 4vw; }

            }

            /* styles for tablet */

            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { /* styles for tablet */

            }';
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);
```

My directory structure looks like this

```
rogersproperties
  |___index.html
  |___css
  |    |___css.php
  |    |___css.css
  |___php
       |___preferences.php
```

Comment: have you made sure to clear your browser cache? when you view the css.css file is it just the one liner? or is it the data you're expecting to be there?

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Clearing the browser cache did the trick. Thank you very much. I have been sitting here for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: It might help to give the css file a new name whenever changes are made. That way the browser won't know it's the same file, and there will be no caching. Otherwise, not just you but also your users will suffer from the same problem.

Comment: just try versioning.

Comment: Eugine Joseph. Could you explain versioning to me please?